# Issue with animating ui elements in unity 3d

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I've added an animation clip to a canvas which animates position and alpha channel of its children *(like buttons etc.)*. Now I'm gonna play this animation via pressing the play button (one of itself's children) as shown as here:

[image: First shot]

[image: Second shot]
<sup>(Click om images to see in full screen)</sup>

I created a trigger in mecanim and sat as the trigger of transiting to that animation but it didn't work. Is there any ways else or was my job correct and did I some mistakes?

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the animator window just making the trigger doesn't do anything. You need to set the trigger by getting a reference to the animator and calling `SetTrigger("yourTriggerName")`. You can call this in the inspector using the UI button's `OnClick()` method.

Go to the inspector for the play button and scroll down to where you see this:

[image: Empty OnClick]

click the plus sign and then drag the game object with the animator you want to trigger onto the field that says **None(Empty)** then select the animator from the drop down menu that appears and select the `SetTrigger` function. Then type in the name of your trigger *Exactly*. Upper case matters. That's it. It should look something like this when you are done:

[image: Finished OnClick]

Obviously, you will have to use the correct GameObject and trigger name so yours will look a little different.

Comment: How so? if you explain a little I can try and help.

Comment: It worked. my mistake. there were mismatches with my clips. Thank you So much